# Show each user's percentile in rep leagues

Tags: script, reputation

I've written a userscript to implement the request from [Can the stack exchange league tables show percent as well as rank?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260366/274165).

Runs in [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and probably others. [Install Show Rep League Percentile](https://www.tuggycomputer.com/nathan/software/userscripts/Show_Rep_League_Percentile.user.js) (should allow auto-updates).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Show Rep League Percentile
// @namespace   com.tuggy.nathan
// @description Displays percentile for the current time period when hovering over a user's rank
// @include     *://stackexchange.com/leagues/*
// @version     1.0.03
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

const percentPerUnit = 100;

var all = new Number(document.querySelector(".sidebar-stats tr:last-child .count")
                     .textContent.replace(",", "").replace(".", ""));
var ranks = document.querySelectorAll(".statsWrapper > :first-child .number");
for (let rank of ranks) {
  let n = new Number(rank.textContent.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").substring(1));
  let pct = n / all, rounding = pct < 0.01 ? 1000 : 100;
  let rpct = (Math.round(pct * percentPerUnit * rounding) / rounding) + "%";
  rank.parentNode.title = rpct;
}
```

I'm considering extending it to add a whole additional column to the table, but I'm not sure it's worth it. (If you want that, let me know!)